# Is content of webpage developed in Flex searchable?

Tags: apache-flex, search, seo

If I developed my webpage entirely using Flex, is it searchable by Google and other search engines? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Google can.

If your browser can show you the contents of your flash object, for Google there is no reason to fail.

Check this article on [Flash indexing on Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html).

Comment: Thanks Chathuranga for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... you're probably taking the wrong approach if you are presenting your Flex app to be indexed.

Allegedly, Google has a Flash Player which allows indexing of Flash content, but no-one has ever seen it in the wild or had it confirm it's actually real.

The best way to approach this is to have an HTML landing page which links to your Flex application. The HTML page gets indexed, and your Flex app doesn't care. If there are things in your App which must be indexed, are you sure Flash was the right approach for it in the first place?

Comment: I thought of building my web app entirely in flex, as it will be more consistent and convenient. But you and JohnB right, I've never seen any page that entirely works in flex, crawled by Google.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of web sites use Flex/Flash objects only were needed, like 1 or more rich UI controls on the page.  The rest is still HTML.  That way you get the best of both worlds, and keep the site fairly simple (important to me), plus the we page is still searchable.

However, to answer your question, yes Google has been working on Flash site indexing algorithms:

- [Google learns to crawl Flash](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-learns-to-crawl-flash.html)

More info:

- [SWF searchability FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html)
- [Making Flash websites searchable](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_searchability.html)